# PHP LDAP authenticates on AD domain, fails on second AD domain with "Incorrect password". (Using MediaWiki LDAP extension)

Tags: php, windows, active-directory, ldap, mediawiki

We have a couple of Active Directory domains of relevance here, which I will call DOMAIN1 and DOMAIN2.

Using PHP code I've included below for reference, we authenticate users against Active Directory when they log on to our dev wiki. As can be seen, the PHP code does this using the MediaWiki LDAP extension. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication

This PHP code has no trouble authenticating DOMAIN1 users, and has worked for years without any problem. Exhibit A1 below shows the LocalSettings.php code, while exhibit A2 shows the successful LDAP authentication log.

Following a company acquisition, DOMAIN2 users now need to use the wiki too. But after updating the PHP code to add DOMAIN2, we find the authentication won't work for DOMAIN2 users. It says "Invalid password" though they enter the correct password. Exhibits B1 and B2 show the PHP and log respectively.

Interestingly, experimentation has shown that "Invalid password" is also what it says if we enter a non-existent username—on either domain. Password error is indicated both at the wiki UI and in the underlying LDAP error data, which is always the same:

```
80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

which internet search results say is a password error.

Finally if a non-existent *domain* name is used, a new LDAP error *is* seen, lending credence to the idea that even though LDAP isn't succeeding on DOMAIN2, it is at least contacting it:

```
80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1772
```

I've spent a couple of days trying to make it work, and I'm left scratching my head. I tried reverting the changes and just replacing DOMAIN1 with the DOMAIN2 details, in case there might be an issue with the list handling, but it made no difference. Nor did changing  $wgLDAPEncryptionType to "clear". In search results I noticed occasional mention of a file called ldap.conf; I didn't find a detailed reference but this sounds likely to be useful, either to change authentication settings or to get more logging etc. But can't see that ldap.conf file was getting used when I tried  it. Exhibit E shows the file with its deliberate invalid/garbage data, which I used in the hope that it should cause an error, thus revealing its correct location, but there was no error about that, which leads me to assume my file wasn't used.

I guess I'm hoping for (a) a solution, if others have had the same authentication issue and fixed it, or failing that (b) clues about ldap.conf (correct location and usage). Also (c) how to get more detailed logging so as to see exactly where the authentication failure occurs.

---

**EXHIBIT A1: original PHP code in LocalSettings.php for DOMAIN1**

```
 $wgLDAPDomainNames = array( 'DOMAIN1'); 
 $wgLDAPServerNames = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'DC1 DC2');
 $wgLDAPSearchStrings = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'DOMAIN1\\USER-NAME');
 $wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'ssl');
```

**EXHIBIT A2: LDAP log of successful authentication on DOMAIN1**

```
session_set_cookie_params: "0", "/", "", "", "1"
Entering validDomain
User is using a valid domain (DOMAIN1).
Setting domain as: DOMAIN1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: USER1
Entering authenticate

Connected successfully
Entering getSearchString
Doing a straight bind
userdn is: DOMAIN1\USER1

Binding as the user
bind=1
ldapconn=Resource id #81
Bound successfully
Entering getUserDN
Created a regular filter: (=USER1)
Entering getBaseDN
basedn is not set for this type of entry, trying to get the default basedn.
Entering getBaseDN
basedn is not set.
Using base: 
Couldn't find an entry
Pulled the user's DN: 
Entering getGroups
Entering checkGroups
Entering getPreferences
Entering synchUsername
Authentication passed
Entering updateUser
setcookie: "DevWikiUserID", "2", "1497608327", "/", "", "", "1"
setcookie: "DevWikiUserName", "USER1", "1497608327", "/", "", "", "1"
setcookie: "DevWikiToken", "", "1481969927", "/", "", "", "1"
session_set_cookie_params: "0", "/", "", "", "1"
Entering validDomain
User is not using a valid domain ().
Setting domain as: invaliddomain
Entering allowPasswordChange
Entering modifyUITemplate
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: USER1
```

With the above logging comes a successful log-in. Wiki pages show that the user is logged in.

**EXHIBIT B1: PHP code in LocalSettings.php updated to add DOMAIN2**

```
$wgLDAPDomainNames = array( 'DOMAIN1',
                            'DOMAIN2'); 
$wgLDAPServerNames = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'DC1 DC2',
                            'DOMAIN2' => 'DC1B DC2B');
$wgLDAPSearchStrings = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'DOMAIN1\\USER-NAME',
                              'DOMAIN2' => 'DOMAIN2\\USER-NAME');
$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( 'DOMAIN1' => 'ssl',
                               'DOMAIN2' => 'ssl');
```

**EXHIBIT B2: LDAP log of unsuccessful authentication on DOMAIN2**

```
session_set_cookie_params: "0", "/", "", "", "1"
Entering validDomain
User is using a valid domain (DOMAIN2).
Setting domain as: DOMAIN2
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: USER2
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering userExists

Entering authenticate

Connected successfully
Entering getSearchString
Doing a straight bind
userdn is: DOMAIN2\USER2

Binding as the user
bind=
ldapconn=Resource id #94
Failed to bind as DOMAIN2\USER2
with password: USER2PASSWORD
Entering allowPasswordChange
Entering modifyUITemplate
```

**EXHIBIT C: LDAP log of deliberate use of non-existent domain**

*Note: it can be seen that this log states "User is using a valid domain", but this only means the domain name is one of those listed in LocalSettings.php, not that a domain of that name actually exists, which it doesn't.*

```
session_set_cookie_params: "0", "/", "", "", "1"
Entering validDomain
User is using a valid domain (NODOMAIN).
Setting domain as: NODOMAIN
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: Nouser
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering getCanonicalName
Username isn't empty.
Munged username: 1
Entering userExists

Entering authenticate

Connected successfully
Entering getSearchString
Doing a straight bind
userdn is: NODOMAIN\Nouser

Binding as the user
bind=
ldapconn=Resource id #94
Failed to bind as NODOMAIN\Nouser
with password: NOPWD
Entering allowPasswordChange
Entering modifyUITemplate
```

**EXHIBIT D: PHP code added to LdapAuthentication.php to output extended LDAP error information on bind failure**

```
if ( !$bind ) {
  .
  .
  .
  define(LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, 0x0032);

  if (ldap_get_option($this->ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error)) {
    echo "Error Binding to LDAP: $extended_error";
  } else {
    echo "Error Binding to LDAP: No additional information is available.";
  }
}
```

**EXHIBIT E: ldap.conf**

*Note: the contents are designed to confirm whether the file's actually being used, hence the inclusion of invalid/garbage text that I hope would throw an error. But no new error was evident, suggesting this file is not being used when present in either `C:\` or `C:\openldap\sysconf\`.*

```
wot a load of rubbish
not a proper conf file

TLS_CACERT C:\openldap\sysconf\certs.pem
TLS_CACERT "C:\openldap\sysconf\certs.pem"

TLS_REQCERT never

TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/pki/tls/certs
TLS_CACERT      /etc/pki/tls/certs/local-bundle.crt
```